# Angular js ellipsis

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there any way where we can use angular js to substring the string and add the ellipsis at the end while ignoring the anchor tag if it is coming inside the substring?

For example, my text is:

> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard
>   dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a
>   galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

I can only show the text up to 70 characters after that ellipsis.

In this case, from "55 - 100 approx" is anchor link, substring chips the string from 0,70 and create a bad string with broken anchor link.

On HTML, I am using:

```
> data-ng-bind-html
```

to parse the Substring.

How can we ignore `< a href="something.html" > < /a >` Tags inside the string and substring other content?

Don't want to use CSS as content can be of any length.

Filter used:

```
filter('customEllipsis', function() {
        return function(input, number) {
            if (input) {
                return input.length > number ? input.substring(0, number) + '...' : input;
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: @mvermand Already removed my comment since the question states OP doesn't want CSS. The CSS approach would not suffer from the broken anchor though.

Comment: @Kunal I think you need a reg-ex to find an un-terminated anchor

Comment: Yes, Something that can substring without damaging the Anchor link.

Comment: Interesting problem. Another issue would be that the anchor tags themselves take up characters, so possibly you would have a lot less than 70 characters left.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Angular sanitizer](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-sanitize.js) to parse html. See this [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/muvevipewu/edit?html,js,output) for an example of usage.

```
app.filter('customEllipsis', function($sce) {
  return function(input, number) {
    if (input) {
      input = input.length > number ? input.substring(0, number) + '...' : input;
      input = $sce.trustAsHtml(input);
      return input;
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular's  built-in filter  `limitTo`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that:

1. Converts the HTML content to a DOM document
2. Performs a depth-first traversal of the document
3. Evaluates all text nodes, cuts off after the maximum length has been reached, and adds the ellipsis
4. Discards remaining nodes
5. Serializes the result back to HTML

The snippet below contains the complete implementation. It ends with an example in which the example string
*`Click <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">this absolutely <b>ah-mah-zing</b> link</a> to access Stackoverflow.`*
gets limited to 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45 and 50 characters respectively.

Run the code snippet to see the results.

```js
function limit(string, maxLength) {
  let visit = function(node) {
    if (count < maxLength) {
      if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        let left = maxLength - count;
        let length = node.nodeValue.length;

        if (length > left) {
          node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.substring(0, left) + '...';
          count += left;
        } else {
          count += length;
        }
      } else {   
        for (let childNode of Array.from(node.childNodes)) {
          visit(childNode);
        }
      }
    } else {
      node.remove();
    }

    return node;
  };
  let dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(string, "text/html");
  let tree = dom.body;
  let count = 0;

  return visit(tree).innerHTML;
}

let string = 'Click <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">this absolutely <b>ah-mah-zing</b> link</a> to access Stackoverflow.';

document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = [20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50]
        .map(maxLength => limit(string, maxLength))
        .join('<br>');
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

**Advantages**

- It preserves all relevant tags, even nested tags
- It's precise because the HTML tags and attributes are not taken into account to determine how many characters to display.

**Disadvantages**

- Performance might not be stellar, although there's still room for optimization (e.g. the serializing back to HTML can be skipped, the `DOMParser` instance can be shared, etc.)